# default notification sound only once

Tags: android, audio, notifications, default

I have an application that uses the Orientation Sensor, and I want to play the default notification sound when the 'y' value is upper than 170 degrees. The thing is that the first time it happens it makes the sound correctly but twice (I suppose this is because of the time it takes to stablish canSound to false) and also after the first time it happens, if 'y' value is again upper than 170,it doesn't sound as I expected to happen.So, the question is, what am I doing wrong with mediaPlayer?

Thanks in advance.

P.D.:This is the part of code I have inside public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) related with my problem.

```
    if(y>170&&canSound)
    {
        canSound=false;
        Uri defaultRingtoneUri=RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try
        {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, defaultRingtoneUri);
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
                {
                    mp.release();
                }
            });
            mediaPlayer.start();
         }
         catch (IllegalArgumentException e) 
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
         catch (SecurityException e)
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
         catch (IllegalStateException e)
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
         catch (IOException e) 
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }    
 }
 else
 {
    if(y<170&&!canSound)
    {
       mediaPlayer.stop();
       mediaPlayer.reset();
       canSound=true;
    }
```

Comment: remove the release and try again

Comment: Thanks Michel. Replacing release for reset it works (without anything inside onCompletion didn´t work),though it keeps sounding despite of stablishing canSound to false (it didn't appear in the code above because of a mistake)